# JPA HSQL does not fetch fields from extended classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I am inserting into HSQL following data:

```
INSERT INTO Consumer(id,ConsumerId,CREATEDBY,CREATEDAT,FK_Service,ConsumerType) VALUES(300,'adsgvcg-cvvce-hvchwec','sm',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,'INTERNAL');
```

I have the following Classes which read from the table:

```
Entity(name = "Consumer")
@Table(name = "Consumer")
public class Consumer extends Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

     @Basic(optional = false)
     @Column(name = "ConsumerId", nullable = false)
     private String ConsumerId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ConsumerType", nullable = false)
    private String ConsumerType;

    @Basic//(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FK_Service", nullable = true)
    private String service;

//Getter Setters etc
```

and the base class looks like:

```
public class Base implements Serializable{

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MODIFIEDBY", nullable = true)
    private String ModifiedBy;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MODIFIEDAT", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp ModifiedAt;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CREATEDBY", nullable = true)
    private String CreatedBy;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CREATEDAT", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp CreatedAt;

//Getter Setters etc
```

When I am running the code, I am getting the following exception:

```
2015-07-25 22:21:12,875 ERROR [main] hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.? (?:?) - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: INSERT INTO Consumer(id,ConsumerId,CREATEDBY,CREATEDAT,FK_Service,ConsumerType) VALUES(300,'adsgvcg-cvvce-hvchwec','smenon2',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,'INTERNAL')
2015-07-25 22:21:12,875 ERROR [main] hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.? (?:?) - user lacks privilege or object not found: CREATEDBY
```

However when I move the fields from the base class to the parent (Consumer) class, this exception no longer occurs and the fields are getting populated as well.

Comment: Try @MappedSuperclass in the Base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [inheritance strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3356) in hibernate 
In your base entity, you need to add an annotation so that hibernate knows which strategy to use.

@MappedSuperclass

or

@Inhertitance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) you can use one of these strategies :

- InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE
- InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS
- InheritanceType.JOINED

This [wikibook page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) can be helpful.